# UITableview text alignment not working in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

First of I'm very sorry to ask this doubt.

I created a table view cell and tried to align it to center.But this is doing nothing.just align in left itself.

This is the code i used.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    if(indexPath.section == 0){


    SDSCaseListCustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//    if (customCell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *cells =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SDSCaseListCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in cells) 
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                customCell = (SDSCaseListCustomCell*)view;
            }
        }
    }
    SDSCase *cases  = [caseList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    customCell.doctor.text = cases.referredDoctor;
    customCell.hospital.text = cases.hospital;  
    //customCell.time.text = cases.referredDoctor;  
    customCell.caseId.text =cases.caseId;  


    return customCell;
    }
    else 
    {
        UITableViewCell  *loadMore = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (loadMore == nil) 
        {

            loadMore = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        }


        loadMore.textLabel.text = @"loadMore";
         loadMore.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 

            return loadMore;
    }


}
```

Can anybody please help me where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: Can I provide different code for set the tableview cell in tableview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [indentationLevel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/indentationLevel)

> indentationLevel Adjusts the indentation level of a cell whose content
>   is indented.
>
> @property(nonatomic) NSInteger indentationLevel Discussion The default
>   value of the property is zero (no indentation). The width for each
>   level of indentation is determined by the indentationWidth property.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later. Declared In
>   UITableViewCell.h

Edit:

If you want to you can create your own label and added as a subview to the contentView. You can not change the alignment of the textLabel the alignment is controlled by the UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Comment: im not clear.can you please give little more explanation how to edit my code.im using Xcode 4.3.2

Comment: for ex: cell.indentationLevel = 10;

Comment: but usually we can adjust the alignment through loadMore.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; this code na

Answer (score 0):

for all your format and syles of a uitableview cell, implement a method layoutsubviews in SDSCaseListCustomCell class and do whatever you want to do in it

like

```
@implementation SDSCaseListCustomCell
.
.
.
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect tFrame =  self.textLabel.frame;
    tFrame.size.width = 235;
    self.textLabel.frame= tFrame;
    self.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

}
.
.
.
@end
```